# whatsapp business api is only used pre-selected company from whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp, facebook-apps, apiclient

I guess whatsapp business api client is only used pre-selected company which whatsapp grant.
So, i want to know my guessing is right or not.

According to official guide, i need to register phone number to whatsapp.
I guess here exist whatsapp menu. but i can't see menu. (Sorry, i dont know the way website display english language)

[image]

Official guide mentions this. "If you cant see WhatsApp account option, you cant use Business API yet"

So i search how can i access Business API, and i can see this in WhatsApp FAQ.
[image]

Finally, according to below link, WhatsApp has granted to 90 pre-selected companies.
https://medium.com/callbell/what-changes-with-the-release-of-the-whatsapp-business-apis-46994316b763

As a result, if i want to use whatsapp business api, i need to use service which is provided official whatsapp partner company like twilio.

Someone tell me that My result is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you either need to fill out the request form to request access to WhatsApp Business API or use existing solution providers like Twilio.

Comment: do you know how much time it takes them to approve form request ?

Comment: currently, it is recommended to use one of the existing solution providers.